# Can not call list from function

Tags: flutter

There is no problem calling class and make list. My problem is I can not reach that list in statefull widget. I miss something...

I call API for data and get "data". It's simply live-search with php.

You can see my try in code where I wrote

> Text(tagObjs), //////////THİS PART CANNOT CALL LIST

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  bool searching = false;
  String term;
  bool error;

  void getSuggestion() async {
    var jsonResponse;
    String url = "API";
    //get suggestion function
    var res = await http.post(url + "?term=" + Uri.encodeComponent(term));

   
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        jsonResponse = json.decode(res.body);
       
        var tagObjsJson = jsonResponse['data'] as List;////////////MAKE LIST PART
        List<Tag> tagObjs =
            tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => Tag.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();
        print(tagObjs[0]);     ////WORK FINE
      });
    } else {
      //there is error
      setState(() {
        error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      .............
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                  ..........
                onChanged: (value) {
                  term = value; //update the value of query
                  getSuggestion(); //start to get suggestion
                },
              ),
              Text(tagObjs), //////////THİS PART CANNOT CALL LIST
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

//search suggestion data model to serialize JSON data
class Tag {
  ...........
}
```

My goal is basicly do foreach in php. With Listview.Builder I am gonna create Rows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `List<Tag> tagObjs` as a class property like `searching`, `term`, and `error`.

```dart
List<Tag> tagObjs = [];
bool searching = false;
String term;
bool error;
```

and remove `List<Tag>` from inside `getSuggestion`

```dart
tagObjs = tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => Tag.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();
```